# The method findAll() in the type CrudRepository<Build,ObjectId> is not applicable for the arguments (Predicate)

Tags: spring-boot, maven, crud-repository

I want to upgrade my spring boot project to 2.6.6 from 1.5.22.RELEASE while upgrading I'm getting the following errors suggest me how to fix it

```
The method findAll() in the type CrudRepository<Build,ObjectId> is not applicable for the arguments (Predicate)

The method findAll() in the type CrudRepository<Build,ObjectId> is not applicable for the arguments (Predicate, PageRequest)
```

Repository:

```
package com.capitalone.dashboard.repository;

import org.springframework.data.querydsl.QueryDslPredicateExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository; 

public interface BuildRepository extends CrudRepository<Build, ObjectId>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Build> 
{
 Build findByCollectorItemIdAndNumber(ObjectId collectorItemId, String number);

 Build findByCollectorItemIdAndBuildUrl(ObjectId collectorItemId, String buildUrl);
 ...

}
```

Client code:

```
Iterable<Build> result;
if (request.getMax() == null) {
    result = buildRepository.findAll(builder.getValue());
} else {
    PageRequest pageRequest =PageRequest.of(0, request.getMax(), Sort.Direction.DESC, "timestamp");
    result = buildRepository.findAll(builder.getValue(), pageRequest).getContent();
}
```

build.class

```
@Document(collection="builds")
public class Build extends BaseModel {
    private ObjectId collectorItemId;
    private long timestamp;
    private String number;
```

I also tried changing to findAllById then got the below error :

> The method findAllById() in the type CrudRepository<Build,ObjectId> is not applicable for the arguments (Predicate)

though the interface is extending QueryDslPredicateExecutor why I'm not able to use findAll(predicate)?

Comment: the Predicates are automatically generated from the method names in the CrudRepository. I think they might not be named properly.

Comment: Could you add the Build so that we can see if the properties collectorItemId and number exist as well as the annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API doc for [CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) and [JpaRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html), I see that `findaAll(Example<s> example)` is only available in the `JpaRepository` interface. (I assume `builder.getValue()` in your code is a single value.)
For `CrudRepository` you would need to use `findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids)`.

Thus, I suggest switching to `JpaRepository` or using `findAllById`.